# How to lock OrmLite SQL database in Android to perform a few reads and then unlock it?

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to perform a group of several queries to my OrmLite db in Android and I want to make sure that no other thread writes to this table in between two of those queries. How do I use ORMLITE in order to lock/unlock the DB for these few queries?

Comment: Maybe inside a transaction: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know there no mechanism supported to get a lock explicitly in SQLite and Ormlite, as its maintain its behaviour itself for locking and releasing the database. But you can create  **Transaction**  for getting a lock till you are doing something and free it as its over.

For **Ormlite** transaction you can see this [Link](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/misc/TransactionManager.html)

For **SQLite** transaction you can see this [Link](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)

Comment: Are you sure the proposed Ormlite solution is going to protect the table from writing until I am in a transaction?

Comment: yes while you are in transaction ..it will have a lock on db.